# Asp.net Membership and Roles Self Contained Web Application

Tags: asp.net, database, security, deployment

I need to quickly wrap some security around an existing ASP.Net 2.0 web app. After thinking about it for a moment, I remembered that Microsoft created that Membership and Roles paradigm a couple of years back, and that Visual Studio could essentially create everything for you.

Thus I forged forward using the built in ASP.Net Web Site Administration Tool and created a simple little security framework around the application. After setting all of the options, Visual Studio created a nice little SQL Express DB called ASPNETDB.MDF right under the newly created App_Data directory of my website. This works great until you deploy it.

After trying to push this app to my DEV server I realized that it's not going to work unless you have SQL Express installed on the hosting machine. Worse yet, I figured that there's essentially no way this would work under a load balanced environment considering the DB itself will only be isolated to one of the N nodes.

Rather than work to script out the DB and shove it into my existing SQL box...I figured I'd ask the StackOverflow if there is a better solution for simple yet secure ASP.Net websites.

I'd love to maintain the existing model yet have the database become a local, or flat-file DB baked right into the application. For the time being I'm even fine with deploying the flat file with each user or role change to counteract the load balanced sites in PROD.

Is there not a way to create some sort of similar setup with a flat file? I thought that was the point of the App_Data folder?

Comment: Personally I'd think it would be less effort to use your existing DB. The ASP.NET security tables for membership, roles and profile shouldn't be too difficult to get set-up. Especially with a load balanced environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom Role & Membership provider that supports a flat file, like XML.  Here is a link to a XML Membership provider, I've seen similar implementations for Roles.

[XML Membership Provider](http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx)

Comment: This looks really interesting and is essentially what I need for a quick and easy deployment. I'm going to mark this as the answer because you're dead on with what I was thinking! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

> > it's not going to work unless you have SQL Express installed on the hosting machine.

Not necessarily. If you still want to use default membership/role providers you can either have the DB server on the hosting machine or have one instance of the DB as a separate server (just change the connection string for providers).

> > Worse yet, I figured that there's essentially no way this would work under a load balanced environment considering the DB itself will only be isolated to one of the N nodes.

This statement is not really correct in this particular situation.

With load-balancing you will not have isolated database, but rather a separate database server.

> I'd love to maintain the existing
>   model yet have the database become a local, or flat-file DB baked right
>   into the application. For the time
>   being I'm even fine with deploying the
>   flat file with each user or role
>   change to counteract the load balanced
>   sites in PROD

If you say that application with proper SQL DB will not scale, I do not understand how flat-file storage can.

You still can keep local SQL Server database and it will work as long as you take responsibility of maintaining the database consistency across different nodes.

In your situation, I would personally use default membership/roles provider as you do now.
But when deploying, just change the connection string to the proper database server.

You will need a database for other stuff anyway, so why not use the same database for all data withing the application (including membership/roles).

Regards.

Comment: After further review I'm not able to talk to my existing DB from the environment that I'm in. I understand the solutions you're pitching...but I'm more interested in some concept of embedded/deployable DB without worrying about scaling at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent solution to this here...http://aspnetxmlproviders.codeplex.com/. Using the dynamic XML you can hack out a simple provider based security model in no time flat.